# Using DOM to create an input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I currently have been working on this code and I can't seem to figure it out. I am planning to make it so that if the radio button is pressed that shipping is not free, that an input field pops up to specifying what the addition cost will be using DOM. I am also trying to figure out how to add text to describe the input field, and to validate the input field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            var c = 1;
            if (c = 1) {
            x.setAttribute("type", "text");

            var sp2 = document.getElementById("emailP");            
    //      var br = document.createElement("br");
    //      sp2.appendChild(br);
    //      alert("added break");           
            var sp2 = document.getElementById("emailP");
            var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;
            parentDiv.insertBefore(x, sp2); 
            c++;
            alert("Added Text Box");
            }
            }
        </script>
        <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="alert('Your form has been submitted.'); return false;">

            <p class="boldParagraph">Upload an Image:</p>
            <input type="file" id="pic" accept="image/*" required>

            <p class="boldParagraph">Name of seller:</p> 
            <input class="averageTextBox" type="text" id="seller" value="" required>

            <p class="boldParagraph" id = "tip3P">Shipping costs are free:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="tip3" value="3" checked /> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="tip3" value="4" onclick="myFunction(); this.onclick=null;"/> No

            <p class="boldParagraph" id = "emailP">Email of seller:</p>
            <input class="averageTextBox" type="email" id="emailAddress" value="" required>

            <p class="boldParagraph">Closing date for auction:</p> 
            <input type="date" id="closeDate" value="" required>

            <br><br>
            <button>Submit</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you want to create invisible text field and show it when you need?

Comment: Correct, So when I press the radio button the input field appears, with text indicating what it is, however if I click there is no fee's, the box should disappear. I'm trying to do this through DOM/JS, by adding inserting it.

Comment: In your case it's better to to change `.style.display` or `.style.visibility` property of element and change the value of `required` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `label` element and populate text using `innerHTML`. and then append to DOM.

Example Snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.innerHTML = "<br>Shipment Cost : ";
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  var c = 1;
  if (c = 1) {
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");

    var sp2 = document.getElementById("emailP");
    //      var br = document.createElement("br");
    //      sp2.appendChild(br);
    //      alert("added break");           
    var sp2 = document.getElementById("emailP");
    var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;
    parentDiv.insertBefore(x, sp2);
    parentDiv.insertBefore(label, x);
    c++;
    alert("Added Text Box");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="alert('Your form has been submitted.'); return false;">

  <p class="boldParagraph">Upload an Image:</p>
  <input type="file" id="pic" accept="image/*" required>

  <p class="boldParagraph">Name of seller:</p>
  <input class="averageTextBox" type="text" id="seller" value="" required>

  <p class="boldParagraph" id="tip3P">Shipping costs are free:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="tip3" value="3" checked />Yes
  <input type="radio" name="tip3" value="4" onclick="myFunction(); this.onclick=null;" />No

  <p class="boldParagraph" id="emailP">Email of seller:</p>
  <input class="averageTextBox" type="email" id="emailAddress" value="" required>

  <p class="boldParagraph">Closing date for auction:</p>
  <input type="date" id="closeDate" value="" required>

  <br>
  <br>
  <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

OR

**You can keep the text box hidden and show it when user clicks no. Also, apply validations only when no is selected for shipment radio button.**

I suggest use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), see the snippet below:

> jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people write JavaScript.

```js
var radioButtons = $("[name=tip3]");
radioButtons.on("change", function() {
  if ($("[name=tip3]:checked").val() == "3") {
    $("#shipmentDetail").hide();
  } else {
    $("#shipmentDetail").show();
  }
})
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
  var flag = true;
  if ($("[name=tip3]:checked").val() == "4") {
    if ($("#shipmentDetail").val() == "") {
      flag = false;
      alert("enter some value");
    }
  }

  //other validations here

  if (flag) {
    $("#form").submit()
  }
})
```

```css
#shipmentDetail {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="#" method="post">

  <p class="boldParagraph">Upload an Image:</p>
  <input type="file" id="pic" accept="image/*" required>

  <p class="boldParagraph">Name of seller:</p>
  <input class="averageTextBox" type="text" id="seller" value="" required>

  <p class="boldParagraph" id="tip3P">Shipping costs are free:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="tip3" value="3" checked />Yes
  <input type="radio" name="tip3" value="4" />No
  <label id="shipmentDetail" for="price">Shipment Cost:
    <input id="price" type="text" value="" />
  </label>
  <p class="boldParagraph" id="emailP">Email of seller:</p>
  <input class="averageTextBox" type="email" id="emailAddress" value="" required>

  <p class="boldParagraph">Closing date for auction:</p>
  <input type="date" id="closeDate" value="" required>

  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I'm attempting to do this with DOM and JS only, I have not yet read much upon Jquery yet, and am trying to see how much manipulating I can do with just DOM/JS alone. So far with my code, I got it to add a input box within, but cannot figure out how to add in a break with text to indicate its for shipping fee cost when the radio button is clicked.

Comment: @Brandon : I have updated the answer is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It is, I greatly appreciate you taking the time to look into my issue. I will try and manipulate it further from here. I didn't really know much about innerHTML until now. Ill be sure to look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace
             alert("Added Text Box");

with:

```
        var additional_fees = prompt("Type in");
        x.setAttribute("value", additional_fees)
```